# Закругленная обводка и блок

Tags: css

Всем привет! Надо сделать так, чтобы блок был с закрулгенными краями и обводка. Помогите!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oyemip/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@bifot](/users/12904/bifot) т.е. как закруглить края вы знаете, а как сделать обводку нет?

```
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000;
```

Comment: Мне нужно и обводку и сам div закруглить

Answer (score 2):

Рабочий пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/Vm46c/)**

**css**

```
#holder {
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  border: 1px black solid;  
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#holder div{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="holder"><div>текст</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
border-radius: 50px; /** это круг */
```

http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius

Comment: Знаю как бы! Но закругляет только конец краев. А мне нужно обводку и конец краев!